# About 5 or 6 color-coding resistor ?

Tags: resistors

Beside 4 color-coding resistor we often use, I heard that there are resistors that have 5 or 6 color-coding. What's the meaning of the fifth and sixth color-coding of these kind resistor ? And which applications we use this kind of resistor ?

Comment: The last two colors give you afaik the tolerance.

Comment: google for "resistor color coding chart" or similar

Comment: such a lazy question... no more than 10 minutes on google to answer it

Comment: @PedroQuadros: seconds you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra bands just gives more precise *spec* of the resistor. The extra band in 5-band color-coded resistor adds one more significant digit. The 6th band gives information about temperature coefficient.

**[5 band](http://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/773171/12_sph0901i_how-to-read-resistor-color-codes.pdf)**

```
Band 1 – First significant digit.
Band 2 – Second significant digit
Band 3 – Multiplier
Band 4 – Tolerance
Band 5 - Reliability/tempco
```

**[5 band with 3 significant digits](http://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/5-band-resistor-calculator)**

```
Band 1 – First significant digit.
Band 2 – Second significant digit
Band 3 – Third significant digit
Band 4 – Multiplier
Band 5 – Tolerance
```

**[6 band](http://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/6-band-resistor-calculator)**

```
Band 1 – first significant digit.
Band 2 – second significant digit
Band 3 – third significant digit
Band 4 – Multiplier
Band 5 – Tolerance
Band 6 – Temperature Coefficient (Tempco)
```

The 5 band 2-significant-digit resistors can be distinguished from the 5 band-3-significant-digit resistors by looking at the spacing between the bands.

Talking about application of these 5-,6-band-resistors, I think it is not the number of bands that decides the application of resistors but it is the value (or *spec*) coded with it.

The resistors with 3 significant digits provide more precision than the other. So these are used in circuits requiring 1% or less precision.

Comment: Does this mean there are never resistors with a temperature coefficient and only two significant digits?

Comment: @Austin No. there are resistors with 2 significant digits and  tempco. See [here](http://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/773171/12_sph0901i_how-to-read-resistor-color-codes.pdf)

Comment: at the risk of going down a rabbit hole, so how do you know the difference between a 2-digit with tempco and 3-digit without? Do only 1% and better tolerance parts have three digits?

Comment: @Austin You can distinguish them by looking at the spacing between the bands. No. they can have tolerance like 10% and 5% also.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 band coding is ok for the E12 or E24 series. When you go to the higher E48 or E96 series, ie higher tolerance, or more accurate bands, the extra digits become necessary. More information here:  [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code)